# Converting Navy sunset/sunrise data into time

Tags: r, time, timestamp, datetime-conversion

I have downloaded the 2015-2017 sunset/sunrise data from the Navy and I am trying to format it into dates and time to further use with other data I have. This is how my data set looks in R.

[image: R screenshot]

I have managed to convert the date into the right R data format. Yet, I still can't convert my rise/set column data from a number/integer format to a time data (as hh:mm).
Based on one internet source, I wrote the following codes:

```
Sun2015$Srise<- format(strptime(Sun2015$Rise, format="%H:%M"))
```

However this gives NA in my data

OR

```
Sun2015$Srise<-str_pad(Sun2015$Rise, 4, pad="0")

Sun2015$Srise<-hour(hm(Sun2015$Srise))
```

Yet, I received the following error:

> Warning message: In .parse_hms(..., order = "HM", quiet = quiet) :
>   Some strings failed to parse.

Is there a better way to convert the columns into the right time format so that I can merge the date and time columns into date-time columns for sunset and sunrise?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your military time to 2400 time strings using `sprint("%04d", data)` and go from there. For example, with the first 5 lines of your data:

```
# Sample of your data
Day <- c("1/1/2015", "1/2/2015", "1/3/2015", "1/4/2015", "1/5/2015")
Rise <- c(652,652,652,653,653)
Set <- c(1755,1756,1756,1757,1757)

sun2015 <- data.frame(Day, Rise, Set)

# Convert to 2400 style strings with leading zeroes where necessary
sun2015$Rise <- sprintf("%04d", sun2015$Rise)
sun2015$Set <- sprintf("%04d", sun2015$Set)

# Merge with your date
sun2015$day_rise <- as.POSIXct(paste0(sun2015$Day, " ",sun2015$Rise), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H%M", origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
sun2015$day_set <- as.POSIXct(paste0(sun2015$Day, " ",sun2015$Set), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H%M", origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")

> sun2015$day_rise
[1] "2015-01-01 06:52:00 UTC" "2015-01-02 06:52:00 UTC" "2015-01-03 06:52:00 UTC" "2015-01-04 06:53:00 UTC"
[5] "2015-01-05 06:53:00 UTC"
> sun2015$day_set
[1] "2015-01-01 17:55:00 UTC" "2015-01-02 17:56:00 UTC" "2015-01-03 17:56:00 UTC" "2015-01-04 17:57:00 UTC"
[5] "2015-01-05 17:57:00 UTC"
```

You can adjust to the appropriate time zone if necessary.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to convert the time to 2400 format. Unfortunately, the last code to combine both time and date for either sunrise and sunset did not work. It gave me NA

Comment: You can share your data structure with the `dput` command. For example, `dput(sun2015)` would provide code to recreate your entire dataset. You can share just the top few rows just by using `dput(head(sun2015)[1:5])` Then we can run the code directly on your data to figure out where your error is coming from.

Comment: #2015 data
Sun2015<-read.csv("Data/Navy data/2015_Navy_pre copy.csv")
Sun2015$Date<-as.Date(Sun2015$Day, "%m/%d/%Y") 

Sun2015$Srise<-sprintf("%04d", Sun2015$Rise)
Sun2015$Sset<-sprintf("%04d", Sun2015$Set)

Sun2015$day_rise<- as.POSIXct(paste0(Sun2015$Date, " ", Sun2015$Srise), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H%M", origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
Sun2015$day_set<- as.POSIXct(paste0(Sun2015$Date, " ", Sun2015$Sset), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H%M", origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")

Comment: dput(Sun2015) dput(head(Sun2015))

Comment: If you run `dput(head(sun2015)[1:5])` in your R console, the output will be code that can produce the same data structure. You should share that in your post.

Comment: Ok, the reason your are getting NA when running my suggested code is that you are concatenating `Sun2015$Date` with `Sun2015$Srise` instead of `Sun2015$Day`. You already converted `Sun2015$Day` to a date format by running `Sun2015$Date<-as.Date(Sun2015$Day, "%m/%d/%Y")`. Note that in my code I used the string formatted `Day` variable rather than the `Date` variable. This is because you want to concatenate your strings together first, and then turn into a time-date object.

Comment: You want to run `Sun2015$day_rise<- as.POSIXct(paste0(Sun2015$Day, " ", Sun2015$Srise), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H%M", origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")` instead of `Sun2015$day_rise<- as.POSIXct(paste0(Sun2015$Date, " ", Sun2015$Srise), format = "%m/%d/%Y %H%M", origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")`

Comment: structure(list(Day = structure(c(1L, 12L, 23L, 26L, 27L, 28L), .Label = c("1/1/2015", 
"1/10/2015", "1/11/2015", "1/12/2015", "1/13/2015", "1/14/2015", 
"1/15/2015", "1/16/2015", "1/17/2015", "1/18/2015", "1/19/2015",), class = "factor"), Rise = c(652L, 
652L, 652L, 653L, 653L, 653L), Set = c(1755L, 1756L, 1756L, 1757L, 
1757L, 1758L), Date = structure(c(16436, 16437, 16438, 16439, 
16440, 16441), class = "Date"), Srise = c("0652", "0652", "0652", 
"0653", "0653", "0653")), .Names = c("Day", "Rise", "Set", "Date", 
"Srise"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I had to remove some of the dates from the output because it was too long for the comments

Comment: Please, do NOT post data in comments. Instead, please edit your question and add the data there. Thank you.